# How to use For/Next loops to print range based on check box status

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, iteration

I am having trouble putting together some code that allows me to look at the status of a check box and print a specified range on another worksheet if the check box equals true and then repeat that loop for a given number of check boxes and ranges.

I am utilizing two different For - Next loops to try and accomplish this task. Below is my current code.

```
Sub PrintGraphs()
Dim i As Integer
Dim r As Integer
    For i = 16 To 18
        If ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("CheckBox" & i).Object.Value = True Then
            For r = 1 To 3
                Worksheets("Cut Tables Graphs").Activate
                    Range("RangeSet" & r).Select
                    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = ("RangeSet" & r)
                    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
                        .PaperSize = xlPaperLetter
                        .Orientation = xlLandscape
                        .Zoom = False
                        .FitToPagesWide = 1
                        .FitToPagesTall = 1
                        .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
                        .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
                        .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
                        .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
                        .CenterHorizontally = True
                        .CenterVertically = True
                    End With
                    Application.PrintCommunication = True
                    Selection.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True
            Next r
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

I am also utilizing Public Constants on a separate module to define the variable "RangeSet".  The code on that module is as follows.

```
Public Const RangeSet1 = "B2:U51"
Public Const RangeSet2 = "W2:AP51"
Public Const RangeSet3 = "B53:U102"
```

I am wanting my code to look at check boxes 16 through 18 and then print the corresponding range in the value of the check box equals true.

Desired outcome:

If check box #16 equals true, then print range "B2:U51", else Next i

If check box #17 equals true, then print range "W2:AP51", else Next i

If check box #18 equals true, then print range "B53:U102", else End Loop

The error I am currently getting is: Run-time error '1004': Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation on the line containing "Range("RangeSet" & r).Select

Any help on finding a solution to this problem would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I feel that the easiest approach would be to create an array with the values you want to record.  Once you've filled the array, you can print it anywhere you want using a for loop.

Comment: I'm fairly new to Excel VBA, would you mind elaborating on your comment, or providing an example that I could reverse engineer.

Answer (score 0):

```
Range("RangeSet" & r).Select
```

Is not a valid range in VBA. you will pass it "RangeSet1" as in a string not a range nor the variable you have declared.

could try

```
if r = 1 then
     Range(RangeSet1).Select
elseif r=2 then
     Range(RangeSet2).Select
elseif r=3 then
     Range(RangeSet3).Select
else
    stop'should never get here?
endif
```

there is a way to do this in one line of code but I can not remember the syntax for it.

Comment: In one line of code this should have the same result:  `Range(Choose(r, RangeSet1, RangeSet2, RangeSet3)).Select`

Comment: I was able to implement the single line of code to choose the variable "r", but it does not tie the choice for "r" back to the appropriate variable "i" selection.  It seems to just print all of the ranges for variable "r".

For example, if only checkbox 17 = true and 16 & 18 =  false, it still prints all three ranges rather than just the range for checkbox 17.  

@DarrenBartrup-Cook

Comment: I was able to get the code to print out the correct ranges based on which check box is checked using an 'If i = 16 Then r = 1 / Elseif i = 17 Then r = 2 / Elseif i = 18 Then r = 3 / End If' statement and also the '(Choose(r, RangeSet1, RangeSet2, RangeSet3)' code.

If the last check box is not checked though, i am given the following error: Run-time error '1004': Unable to get the OLEObject property of the Wroksheet class.  If the last check box is checked though, I do not get the error.  Any thoughts on what could be causing this??

Comment: With my code above you should just be able to replace "Range("RangeSet" & r).Select" with my example the rest of the code should work fine. If you wanted you could change r=1 to check box #16.checked = true etc

Answer (score 0):

This is how I'd write the code

```
Sub PrintGraphs()

    Dim i As Integer

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Cut Tables Graphs")
        With .PageSetup
            .PaperSize = xlPaperLetter
            .Orientation = xlLandscape
            .Zoom = False
            .FitToPagesWide = 1
            .FitToPagesTall = 1
            .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
            .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
            .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
            .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
            .CenterHorizontally = True
            .CenterVertically = True
        End With
        Application.PrintCommunication = True
        For i = 16 To 18
            If .OLEObjects("CheckBox" & i).Object.Value = True Then

                .Range(Choose(i - 15, RangeSet1, RangeSet2, RangeSet3)).PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True

            End If
        Next i
    End With

End Sub
```

There's no need for variable r - if you select CheckBox16 you want to print range 1 - so remove 15 from i and you get 1 - choose that range (hope that made sense).

I'm also assuming that the 'ActiveSheet' (the one with the tickboxes) is "Cut Tables Graphs".

I've included your original code at the bottom with some comments.

```
Sub PrintGraphs()
Dim i As Integer
Dim r As Integer
    'This will work - providing the correct sheet is active.
    For i = 16 To 18
        If ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("CheckBox" & i).Object.Value = True Then

            'This will cycle through all three no matter which checkbox was ticked.
            For r = 1 To 3

                'No need to activate the sheet.  Especially if it's the ActiveSheet.
                Worksheets("Cut Tables Graphs").Activate

                    'No need to select a range before working on it.
                    Range("RangeSet" & r).Select

                    'This only needs doing once - not at all if it's the default anyway.
                    'As it's inside the 1 to 3 loop it will happen 3 times.
                    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = ("RangeSet" & r)
                    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
                        .PaperSize = xlPaperLetter
                        .Orientation = xlLandscape
                        .Zoom = False
                        .FitToPagesWide = 1
                        .FitToPagesTall = 1
                        .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
                        .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
                        .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
                        .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
                        .CenterHorizontally = True
                        .CenterVertically = True
                    End With
                    Application.PrintCommunication = True

                    'Rather than select the range and print the selection,
                    'just reference the range and print it.
                    Selection.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True
            Next r
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```